# I could use some guidance with LinkedLists in java. Specifically adding an object to a linked list in another class

Tags: java, class, import, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to get this program to add a "Product" object to my linked list on 
ProductList." (Once i get that I can do the others) I'm not sure if I made the LinkedList in my main right, or if I even need one but I just cant seem to figure out how to do it and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
public class Product{
    //Private variable names
    private String prodID;
    private String prodName;
    private int qty;
    private float unitCost;

    //Default Constructor
    public Product(){
        this.prodID = "";
        this.prodName = "";
        this.qty = 0;
        this.unitCost = 0.0f;
    }

    //Constructor with arguments
    public Product(String tmpProdID, String tmpProdName, int tmpQty, float tmpUnitCost){

        this.prodID   =   tmpProdID;
        this.prodName =   tmpProdName;
        this.qty      =   tmpQty;
        this.unitCost =   tmpUnitCost;
    }

    public void setProdID(String tmpProdID){
        this.prodID = tmpProdID;
    }
    public void setProdName(String tmpProdName){
        this.prodName = tmpProdName;
    }
    public void setProdQty(int tmpQty){
        this.qty = tmpQty;
    }
    public void setUnitCost(float tmpUnitCost){
        this.unitCost = tmpUnitCost;
    }

    public String getProdID(){
        return this.prodID;
    }
    public String getProdName(){
        return this.prodName;
    }
    public int getQty(){
        return this.qty;
    }
    public float getUnitCost(){
        return this.unitCost;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Prod ID: " + prodID + ". Prod name: " + prodName + ". Prod qty: " + qty + ". Prod unit cost: " + unitCost;
    }
}

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ProductList{

    //Creating a linked list of products
    private LinkedList<Product> prodList = new LinkedList<Product>();

    public void addProduct(Product tmpProduct){
        prodList.add(tmpProduct);
    }

    public void addProduct(int tmpIndex, Product tmpProduct){
        prodList.add(tmpIndex, tmpProduct);
    }

    public void addFirst(Product tmpProduct){
        prodList.addFirst(tmpProduct);
    }

    public void clear(){
        prodList.clear();
    }

    public boolean contains(Product tmpProduct){
        return prodList.contains(tmpProduct);
    }

    public Product get(int tmpInt){
        return prodList.get(tmpInt);
    }

    public int indexOf(Product tmpProduct){
        return prodList.indexOf(tmpProduct);
    }

    public void remove(Product tmpProduct){
        prodList.remove(tmpProduct);
    }

    public String printAllProducts(){
        return "Something";
    }

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TestProdList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<ProductList> mainList = new LinkedList<ProductList>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Creating the switch variable.
        int choice = 0;
        //Creating a menu driven program.
        String menu = "\nWhich would you like to do?" +
                        "\n1 - Add a Product."+
                        "\n2 - Find a Product by Name." +
                        "\n3 - Find the Product at a Particular Position." +
                        "\n4 - Remove a product." +
                        "\n5 - Clear the list of Prodcuts" +
                        "\n6 - Print the entire inventory of Products" +
                        "\n7 - Quit";
        System.out.println(menu + "\n\nEnter your selection: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        while (choice != 7){
            switch(choice){
            case 1: 
                String prodID;
                String prodName;
                int qty;
                float unitCost;

                System.out.println("Please enter the product id: ");
                prodID = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter the product name: ");
                prodName = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a quantity: ");
                qty = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a unit cost: ");
                unitCost = input.nextFloat();
                input.nextLine();   

                mainList.add(new prodList(prodID,prodName,qty,unitCost));
                break;

            case 2:
                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            case 4:
                break;

            case 5:
                break;

            case 6:
                break;

            case 7:
                break;

            default: 
                System.out.println("\n~~~Invalid Selection~~~\n");
                break;
            } //End of Switch statement 
        }











    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of your `ProductList` class? It seems to just have a `LinkedList` instance variable and methods that just perform the same function as the `LinkedList`? Why not just make a `LinkedList` of `Product` objects in main instead of a `LinkedList` of your `ProductList`s?

Comment: I have to do it this way based on my instructions. I also think that it doesn't make any sense and is completely pointless but I have to have it in there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ProductList` as an own class. Just use `LinkedList<Product> mainList = new LinkedList<Product>()` in your main class.

If you have the requirement to introduce `ProductList` you should to it as follows:

```
public class ProductList extends LinkedList<Product> {
    // only put required constructors here
    // all methods from LinkedList are inherited automatically with data type Product
}
```

In `main` instantiate as `ProductList mainList = new ProductList();` and use as `mainList.add(new Product())`;